# javascript change position depending on number

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysqli

When people fill in a form, all the data gets send and saved in a database.
For example:

[image: form]

Now people fill in the distances of the axles (In the next page), and the axle distances get updated. They do the same for the bogie table (Tough not with distances but with bogie numbers)

After this all is filled in, the DB looks like this:

Train information:
[image: Train information db]

axle:
[image: axle database]

bogie:
[image: bogie database]

Now with the folowing information, it makes a train shape.

[image: End result]

Now i make this shape, by selecting the number of axles, and turn them in a circle.
I set the distances by selecting the axle table, and use margin-left.

Now. The actual things that need to be added, have a axle distances of 1000-4000 each. So when i add that, the train will be huge if it takes shape.

So i was thinking, (but don't know if it is posible) to instead of set the end result distance by the axle distance. But with the bogie numbers.

So axle 1 and 2 have the bogie number 1. And i want the bogie number 1 to be on the left.
axle 3 and 4 have the bogie number 2. And i would like to have those like 200px next to the number 1.
axle 5 and 6 have the bogie number 3. And i would like to have those 200px next to the number 2. Etc. Etc.

This is how to end_results makes it shape:

```
<div id="axle_position2">
            <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $axlefigure){ ?>
                    <div style="margin-left:<?php echo $axlefigure['distance'];?>px;"> 
                        <?php echo $axlefigure['axle'] ?>
                    </div>
            <?php
                } 
            ?>
        </div>
```

The function it does is just a: SELECT * FROM axle where train_id = train_id

EDIT:

Here a example:

[image: Example of result]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Sidd Now i make this shape, by selecting the number of axles, and turn them in a circle. I set the distances by selecting the axle table, and use margin-left.

Now. The actual things that need to be added, have a axle distances of 1000-4000 each. So when i add that, the train will be huge if it takes shape.

So i was thinking, (but don't know if it is posible) to instead of set the end result distance by the axle distance. But with the bogie numbers.

Comment: So the distance between axles doesn't matter anymore, right?

Comment: correct @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this. Here is one possible solution:

As the distance between axles is not important anymore (specified in the comments), focus on the bogies. Select the bogies and their axels like this:

```
SELECT bogie_nr, GROUP_CONCAT(axle_id) AS axles
FROM   `bogie` 
WHERE   train_id = 17 
GROUP BY bogie_nr
```

This select will return the number of the bogie, and a comma-separated list of the axles in that particular bogie. The only thing left for you to do would be to traverse the results like you did, and break the `axles` string by comma.

Finally, to display the results, wrap the axles within the bogie and add styling appropriately. Something like this: (`$bogies` will be the resultset from the query above)

```
<?php foreach($bogies as $bogie) { ?>
    <div class="bogie" id="bogie<?php echo $bogie["bogie_nr"]; ?>"> 
        <?php 
            $axles = explode(",", $bogie["axles"]);
            foreach($axles as $axle) {
        ?>
            <div class="axle"><?php echo $axle; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I didn't add the styling to make it *clearer*, but the idea would be that the `.bogie` class would have 200px of `margin-left` (to separate it from the next bogie), and the `.axle` class would have whatever `margin-left` you want to add.